# Why does a bluepill's outfit get damaged when an agent's clothing gets damaged?

Tags: the-matrix

[image]

How can this be? When an agent possesses a human, it overwrites the victim's (let's call him Gary) RSI. The agent can't be a "hologram." Its tie, glasses, Desert Eagle, and earpiece are physically there. The agent owns them. So how can Gary's clothes suffer damage in the first place? They're not "organic" articles.

Does this mean Agents are actually "holograms" that cover the victim, or do they replace the person completely, becoming human in the process?

Comment: *"Does this mean Agents are actually "holograms" that cover the victim.."* Given the visual representation of both the agents and people in the matrix are effectively computer generated, I'd say it mostly depends on the program doing the generating..

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I would say that the agents don't have "bodies" of their own - they are essentially viruses that override the "shell" program representing the blue-pill. They're still using the shell's matter - or whatever the in-Matrix virtual equivalent is - to create the gun, earpiece, etc. Therefore damage, or lost bits, would affect the base shell even after it reverts back to its original form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, this raises an even bigger question: Why do the Agents need to possess normal people *at all?*  Why can't they just appear wherever they need to?

If it's just about not breaking the illusion of reality by having MiBs appear out of thin air, they could simply appear in a secluded area - around a corner or in a closet where no one can see them.

There must be some reason why an agent NEEDS to commandeer a regular person's body.  Perhaps maintaining the virtual reality of the matrix has some equivalent to the conservation of matter - the matrix can't just *create* new matter (or it doesn't *want to*, perhaps because it's somehow costly.)  So, instead of creating an agent's body out of wholecloth, it takes an existing person in the vicinity and *transforms* them into the agent.  Not a hologram, but a transmutation of matter.

The person's body becomes the agent's body, the person's clothes become the agent's clothes, etc.  Maybe the person's purse (or other accessories) become the agent's gun, or if the person has no "spare material" then the matrix could use some nearby trash from a waste bin to make the gun and other items necessary.

When the agent leaves, and the person reverts to normal, the matrix translates damage to the body and clothing as it was suffered by the agent - because there is less material remaining than there  was before, and "matter" must be "conserved."  Presumably, the shreds of the agent's clothing left floating on the wind would also revert to shreds of the person's clothing, and so on.

---

If you'll allow me to go off on a tangent, this reminds me of how magic worked in White Wolf's *Mage: The Ascension* role-playing game (an RPG which my friends compared the Matrix to regularly, when the movie first came out.)  In the game, there's "coincidental" magic and "vulgar" magic.  Having an agent appear out of thin air would be vulgar, because it's plainly impossible for a person to appear out of nowhere, but having a previously existing person that no one was paying attention to become an agent *could be* considered coincidental*, because *a person* was always there, so as long as no one noticed the change it's like *the agent* was always there.  This plays nicely into the Matrix's concept of "deja vu."

* *Mage* generated more than just a little controversy over what exactly constituted "coincidental" or "vulgar" magic - I'd rather not get into a huge  argument over Mage RAW in the comments, please - **that's what RPG.SE is for.**  I'm not saying this is how the RPG should be played, I'm only saying it's an internally consistent comparison, given the rules that the Matrix's virtual reality *appears to be playing by* in the films.

Comment: But then how/why do redpills get to materialize and dematerialize when they go through the phones?

Comment: @Devsman: the Agents have to follow the rules, the redpills don't.  If they're damaging the integrity of the Matrix by doing so, well, that's not really their problem now is it? :-)

Comment: The way I see it (and continuing with the Mage analogy), redpills follow a *different set* of rules.  I mean, they still need to reach a phone to get out.  Also, the whole phone thing is for *entering* and *leaving* the Matrix - stepping in and out of reality itself, as it were.  Agents are programs in the Matrix, they just move around within it.